# I have a problem with the screen position on chrome mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome, mobile

I am using REACT JS, and this is on chrome mobile, there is something i don't understand.
On the 1st picture you can see the menu is on the bottom of my mobile screen navigator after I put the adress localhost....
After page loaded the menu, is staying on the bottom of the screen.  that's not what I want.
[1st BUG ON LOAD PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEDMw.jpg)

[2nd AFTER 1 press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzowk.jpg) 
Then after 1 press on the screen my menu is automatically on the middle of the screen, that's what i want ! it's ok !

That's the only component on my reactjs app who doing that.
How can I resolve this problem ?

header:

``html

Netfrics

```

css :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100vw - 1px);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: vars.$background-color;
  user-select: none;
  user-select: unset;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

body,
#root,
.body {
  height: 100%;
}
.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: -webkit-fill-available; // i tryed 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `height:100dvh` on every selector you want to be 100%.
I think this is happening because mobile browser address bar messes with the view port.
Try out and tell me the result. I'm sure we'll figure something out

```
.selector{
 height:100vh; // fallback value
 height:100dvh;
}
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thx to try to help me !
This not work :(

Good to know,  it's only doing that on chrome mobile, no problem with mozilla or some other